# RuntimeException on newly created NavDrawer

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, runtimeexception

So, I'm a newbie with Android app development, and I'm getting the following error on a newly create Navigation Drawer activity (Incoming Stack trace):

```
04-01 16:50:52.113 8917-8917/pt.bluecover.wearable3d E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pt.bluecover.wearable3d/pt.bluecover.wearable3d.DrawerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
                                                                           at pt.bluecover.wearable3d.DrawerActivity.onCreate(DrawerActivity.java:37)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at pt.bluecover.wearable3d.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:101)
                                                                           at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
                                                                           at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:861)
                                                                           at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
                                                                           at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1137)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4735)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881) 
                                                                           at pt.bluecover.wearable3d.DrawerActivity.onCreate(DrawerActivity.java:37) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I also have the following classes referenced in the trace:

```
package pt.bluecover.wearable3d;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DrawerActivity extends Activity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drawer, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((DrawerActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

And this one:

```
package pt.bluecover.wearable3d;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation drawer.
 * See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
 * design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.drawer_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return getActivity().getActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

Both where auto-generated by adding a Navigation Drawer Activity to the project and haven't been modified yet...

EDIT: activity_drawer.xml code here:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pt.bluecover.wearable3d.DrawerActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="pt.bluecover.wearable3d.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/drawer_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: can you also post the layout for `DrawerActivity` ?

Comment: Added the activity_drawer.xml content.

Comment: You have a NullPointerException at line 101 of `NavigationDrawerFragment.java` What is that line?

Comment: Can you also post the fragment layout ?

Comment: It's a bit hard to guess the line number 18 - which line is the error referring to? Can you just post the line below? I suspect there is some XML error or some error in class usage in line 18.

Comment: It's most likely `getActionBar()` is returning null. Are you using an ActionBar theme ?

Comment: @Christian The XML isn't the problem. Line 18 is the `<fragment>` tag and the Fragment code is throwing a NullPointer.

Comment: This is the line 100 to 108 of the Fragment:

mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                }));

Comment: The line 101 is the "getActionBar().getThemedContext()" part

Comment: @arsent last time I checked I ain't using an ActionBar...

Comment: That's it then. Use a theme that has an ActionBar - `Theme.AppCompat.Light` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need a themed context for an Adapter, but this section is throwing a NullPointerException.

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
        android.R.id.text1,
        new String[]{
                getString(R.string.title_section1),
                getString(R.string.title_section2),
                getString(R.string.title_section3),
        }));
```

Try using `getActivity()` instead of `getActionBar().getThemedContext()` because `getActionBar()` will return null if you aren't using a theme in `styles.xml` that contains an ActionBar for the parent Activity.

In code...

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getActivity(), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. To be able to get the action bar you should have it in the theme.

```
android:Theme.Light
```

will do. In your `styles.xml` use this for the Theme that you are using for the activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

Comment: thanks. `android:Theme.Light` will work in that case